# Add nested objects together

Tags: javascript, object, math

Is it possible to add nested objects together. I know Object.assign can merge two objects. For example:

```
const target = { a: 1, b: { c: 2, d: 3 } };
const source = { e: 7, b: { c: 1, d: 5 } };
const returnedTarget = Object.assign(target, source);

returnedTarget = { a: 1, b: { c: 1, d: 5 }, e: 7 }
```

But is there anyway to add variables C and D rather than overwriting them with the source?

An actual use case example:

```
[ 
    Character1: {
        kills: { value: 10.0, displayValue: "10" },
        deaths: { value: 5.0, displayValue: "5" }
    },
    Character2: {
        kills: { value: 20.0, displayValue: "20" },
        deaths: { value: 15.0, displayValue: "15" }
    },
]

//Expected Result: 

[
    Merged: {
        kills: { value: 30.0, displayValue: "30" },
        deaths: { value: 20.0, displayValue: "20" }
    }
]
```

Comment: You’d probably need [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). `Object.assign` isn’t the right tool here. If you want to merge nested objects, you’d also need to do it recursively.

Comment: An issue is that `displayValue` is a *string* not a number, so you'll need to tweak the linked solution to cast the property value to a number first, so that addition works (and then turn it back to a string at the end)

Comment: That's not too bad, Just a quick parseInt() wrapper around the objects which define as isNaN() right?

Comment: `parseInt` will round to an *integer*, you just want a number, so use `Number`